# Need simplification of this formula

Tags: functions, summation

I am a Computer Science student not good with advanced mathematics. I need to implement some math formulas in programming, but cannot I understand them properly. Can someone please simplify the following formula for me. Those $3$ variables are confusing me.

$$fit_j = \max_k \sum_{i \in m_k} fit_{j,k,i}$$

Description:
Its a fitness function in Genetic Algorithm. m_k is a set of values.
We are calculating Fit(j).

Assume j is fixed.

i is any value from m_k set

k is just a number assigned to person. For example we are calculating Fit(j) for Kth person and each person has a m_k set from which we will choose i.

Doubts:

1. What are we taking Max of?
2. What does k under Max mean?
3. What do I take sum of? I know that j will be fixed.
   But i and k are confusing me.
   How do I approach it?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please provide some more context about what you are working on. As written, you formula just says "Sum over some numbers, and then take the maximum among multiple such sum.". There is nothing to tell you without some more information.

Comment: @Simon I have edited the question and added more information. Please tell me if I need to mention more in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain it:

- for every $j,k,i$, the value $f_{j,k,i}$ is just a number, lets assume all three indices are integers $1,2,3,\dots$.
- Furthermore, each $m_k$ needs to be a set of numbers. For example $m_1=\{1,2,3\}$, $m_2=\{3,4\}$ or something.
- Then for $k=1$ sum is simply understood as
  \begin{align}
  \sum_{i\in m_1}f_{j,1,i} = \sum_{i\in \{1,2,3\}}f_{j,1,i}=f_{j,1,1}+f_{j,1,2}+f_{j,1,3}
  \end{align}
  In general, for each value of $k$, you have such a sum.
- The maximum is taken over these sums, i.e.:
  \begin{align}
  \max_k \sum_{i\in m_k}f_{j,k,i}&=\max(\sum_{i\in m_1}f_{j,1,i}\quad,\quad \sum_{i\in m_2}f_{j,2,k}\quad,\quad\dots) \\
  &= \max(f_{j,1,1}+f_{j,1,2}+f_{j,1,3}\quad,\quad f_{j,2,3}+f_{j,2,4}\quad,\quad\dots)
  \end{align}

Hope this helps to clarify the notation.

Comment: This makes most of the things clear. Thanks!